# Use jQuery data and hide if is equal or less

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the div if data-order is equal or less than the input value, like :

```
<input type="text" name="budgetmax" value="50000" />

<div class="user-item" data-order="5000">asdddsdf </div>
```

and this the jquery:

```
if(jQuery('input[type="text"][name="budgetmax"]').val() < jQuery('.user-item').data('order') )  
    {   
     jQuery('.user-item').hide();    
    }
```

But so far seems not to work :(

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote (`"`) and accompanying closing bracket (`]`) from your `[name="budgetmax'` selector declaration

Comment: Anyway is not working

Answer (score 1):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u8pv77vk/)**

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function(){
    if($('.user-item').data('order')<=$(this).val()){
        $('.user-item').hide(200);
    }
    else{
        $('.user-item').show(200);
    }
});
```

on `blur` event of the input, it will check and do as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You confused `<` with `>`. If you want to hide div when `data-order is equal or less than the input value`, then your code should be:

```
if ($('input[type="text"][name="budgetmax"]').val() > $('.user-item').data('order')) {
    $('.user-item').hide();
}
```